# replicate/repeat string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to replicate a string by a specified number of times with bigquery? Here's a toy example of what I would like to achieve ...

Input:

```
id | count
----------
a  | 1
b  | 2
c  | 3
```

Replicate id by count (i.e. desired output):

```
id | newstr
----------
a  | a
b  | bb
c  | ccc
```

It seems like this functionality is provided by `REPLICATE` in other sql variants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a UDF. It will be a lot slower anyway. Just use the SQL function `REPEAT` (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#repeat)):

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  data AS (
  SELECT
    'a' AS id,
    2 AS repititions
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'b' AS id,
    3 AS repititions)
SELECT
  id,
  repititions,
  REPEAT(id,
    repititions) AS repeated
FROM
  data
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @VasilyBronsky Average times. Standard SQL. Caching off. **w/o UDF:** 1.73s **w/ UDF:** 7.16s

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no REPLICATE() function in BigQuery but you can create UDF function like this:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION REPLICATE(x STRING, y FLOAT64)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return x.repeat(y);;
""";

WITH data AS (SELECT 'a' as id, 2 as count),
     data1 AS (SELECT 'b' as id, 3 as count)
SELECT id, REPLICATE(id,count) as newstr FROM data
UNION ALL
SELECT id, REPLICATE(id,count) as newstr FROM data1
```

In that case output will be:

```
Row id  newstr 
1   a   aa
2   b   bbb
```